# visual style enabled by ActivateActCtx doesn't affect tab control

Tags: winapi, windows-10, themes

I did enable the visual styles using this code:

```
void EnableVisualStyles2(void)
{
    TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    GetSystemDirectory(dir, sizeof(dir) / sizeof(*dir));

    ACTCTX actCtx = {0};
    actCtx.cbSize = sizeof(ACTCTX);
    actCtx.dwFlags =  ACTCTX_FLAG_RESOURCE_NAME_VALID |
                      ACTCTX_FLAG_SET_PROCESS_DEFAULT |
                      ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID;
    actCtx.lpSource = L"shell32.dll";
    actCtx.lpAssemblyDirectory = dir;
    actCtx.lpResourceName = (LPCTSTR) 124;
    ULONG_PTR cookie = FALSE;
    HANDLE h = CreateActCtx(&actCtx);
    assert(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    assert(ActivateActCtx(h, &cookie));
}
```

the buttons are fine but the TabControl and ProgressBar are still using the old style:

[image]

it isn't strictly something with the machine, I've just created a regular manifest, like below, and the tab control UI is fine.

the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

it's fine:

[image]

full code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void InitComControls();
void InitComControls();
void CreateTab(HWND hwnd);
void InsertTabItem(HWND tabHwnd, UINT id, LPWSTR text);
void EnableVisualStyles2(void);

HINSTANCE ghInstance;
HWND hTab;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    MSG  msg = {0};
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.lpszClassName = L"Window";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    
    EnableVisualStyles2();
    InitComControls();
    if(!RegisterClass(&wc)) {
        return -1;
    }

    int width = 540;
    int height = 460;
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    int cx = (screenWidth - width) / 2;
    int cy = (screenHeight - height) / 2;
    hwnd = CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Window",
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                        cx, cy, width, height, NULL, NULL, 
                        hInstance, NULL);
    ghInstance = hInstance;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

  switch(msg)
  {
      case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 1...",
          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
          50, 10, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 18, NULL, NULL);
        CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is label 2...",
          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
          50, 40, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 19, NULL, NULL);
          CreateTab(hwnd);
        CreateWindow(L"button", L"A",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
            110, 140, 90, 25, 
            hwnd, (HMENU) 20, NULL, NULL);
        CreateWindow(L"button", L"B",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
            210, 140, 80, 25, hwnd,
            (HMENU) 21, NULL, NULL);
        HWND hProgressBar =
        CreateWindowEx(PBS_SMOOTH,
            PROGRESS_CLASS, NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            210, 180, 200, 20,
            hwnd, (HMENU) 22, NULL, NULL);
        SendMessage(hProgressBar, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);
      break;

      case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          return 0;
  }

  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void CreateTab(HWND hwnd)
{
  hTab =
   CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROLW, NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_TABSTOP,
            100, 80, 400, 250,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU) 1,
            NULL,
            NULL);
    InsertTabItem(hTab, 2, L"Tab 1");
    InsertTabItem(hTab, 3, L"Tab b");
}

void InsertTabItem(HWND tabHwnd, UINT id, LPWSTR text)
{
    TCITEMW tci = {0};
    tci.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    tci.pszText = text;
    tci.cchTextMax = lstrlenW(text);
    SendMessage(tabHwnd, TCM_INSERTITEM, id, (LPARAM) &tci);
}

void InitComControls()
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);
}

void EnableVisualStyles2(void)
{
    TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    GetSystemDirectory(dir, sizeof(dir) / sizeof(*dir));

    ACTCTX actCtx = {0};
    actCtx.cbSize = sizeof(ACTCTX);
    actCtx.dwFlags =  ACTCTX_FLAG_RESOURCE_NAME_VALID |
                      ACTCTX_FLAG_SET_PROCESS_DEFAULT |
                      ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID;
    actCtx.lpSource = L"shell32.dll";
    actCtx.lpAssemblyDirectory = dir;
    actCtx.lpResourceName = (LPCTSTR) 124;
    ULONG_PTR cookie = FALSE;
    HANDLE h = CreateActCtx(&actCtx);
    assert(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    assert(ActivateActCtx(h, &cookie));
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Your call to `InitCommonControlsEx()` is not loading `ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS`, which may explain why the ProgressBar is not being styled properly.  But your tab control should be. Have you tried using `CreateWindowEx()` instead of `CreateWindow()` for the tab control?

Comment: Added `ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS` and switch to `CreateWindowEx()` but neither made any difference

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems that the progress bar is not the old style. If you want to achieve the effect in the second screenshot, you can try to cancel the call to the `InitCommonControlsEx` function.

Comment: And you can try `icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES | ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS | ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;`

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT adding `ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES` it work! Thank you! post it as answer so I can accept. You're right about the progress bar in the second screenshot doesn't seem to be old style. If I cancel the call to `InitCommonControlsEx` wouldn't it prevent the tab control in new style to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex):

You can try

```
icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES | ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS | ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
```

In this way, you can continue to call the `InitComControls` function to ensure the loading of the table control.